# Maven print illegal characters instead of accented characters

Tags: xml, maven, unicode, utf-8

This XML structure should be OK i think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    ...
    <name>áéééöüúű</name>
```

If this XML is opened in an XML viewer, or a simple browser gives a fine result, but executing a mvn command result:

> [INFO] Building **ßÚÚÚ÷Ř˙ű** 0.6

Do not get how can i force mvn to print in proper way these characters. Any idea? Or is it not possible maybe (without rewriting the source)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from your comments that you're using Windows. Windows command line doesn't not support UTF-8 nor (paradoxically) Windows-XXXX encodings.

Use `-Dfile.encoding=cp852` (or `-Dfile.encoding=cp850`, or `-Dfile.encoding=cp437`, or [any other of these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage#IBM_PC_.28OEM.29_code_pages)).

Comment: very nice try Karol S, the weird thing is that, Jenkins log/console says like this:
[INFO] Building **F?????? ?** 0.6... Hmm... I have an ide based on your supports

Comment: Now with adding -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 it shows:
[INFO] Building F���� �� 
:(( Any idea?

Comment: @czupe Jenkins may be using `ISO-8859-1`, `Windows-1252` or `Windows-1250` encoding.

Comment: +1 give up: Windows console is just broken for Unicode from apps using the MS C runtime (including Java) and the possible workarounds are impractical.

Comment: Seems your solution is working just needed a Jenkins restart (dunno why)

Answer (score 1):

Might be your default system encoding is a single byte encoding. Try and tell Maven explicitly to use UTF-8 via the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable by adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to it.

Comment: Ok, i try it Ralf, thanks!
Now it is writing out: 
[INFO] Building ├í├ę├ę├ę├Â├╝├║┼▒ 0.6
Other characters:) dunno whats going on :S

Comment: What is the actual encoding of the POM.xml? Maybe it is not UTF-8 encoded after all?

Comment: It is encoded to UTF-8, 100% sure, the thing is that Karol S write, i use Windows command line (and if i switch to UTF-8 with "chcp 6500" windows command, it is still no good).